# How to trigger UIControlEventValueChanged of UISlider without touch UISlider in iOS?

Tags: ios, uislider

I have create an UISlider like the following code:

```
BrightnessSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sliderXpoint, 530, sliderwidth, 20)];
BrightnessSlider.minimumValue = 0;
BrightnessSlider.maximumValue = 100;
BrightnessSlider.value = 50;
BrightnessSlider.continuous = YES;
[BrightnessSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(BrightnessSliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[BrightnessSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(BrightnessSliderTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And it will trigger the following event when I touch the `UISlider`.

```
- (void)BrightnessSliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    BrightnessLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.0f", NSLocalizedString(@"Brightness", @""), sender.value];
}
```

I want to trigger the `UIControlEventValueChanged` without touch the UISlider. 
For example , When I set the value to UISlider like the following code:

```
[BrightnessSlider setValue:(BrightnessSlider.value + 1)];
```

How do I trigger the `UIControlEventValueChanged` of `UISlider` without touch `UISlider` in iOS?

Comment: Off-topic, but **please** make instance names (variable names) lower case, and keep upper case to types. As it stands right now, `BrightnessSlider` looks like a class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this to trigger action programmatically:

`[BrightnessSlider sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Answer (score 0):

You can fire

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [BrightnessSlider sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[BrightnessSlider sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
});
```

The key is make sure you do in main thread.